# Countering the Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer's Draconic Presence

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, charmed

> Beginning at 18th level, you can channel the dread presence of your Dragon ancestor, causing those around you to become awestruck or Frightened. As an action, you can spend 5 Sorcery Points to draw on this power and exude an aura of awe or fear (your choice) to a distance of 60 feet. **For 1 minute or until you lose your Concentration (as if you were casting a Concentration spell), each Hostile creature that starts its turn in this aura must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be Charmed (if you chose awe) or Frightened (if you chose fear) until the aura ends.** A creature that succeeds on this saving throw is immune to your aura for 24 hours.

Per the rules established in regards to the Draconic Presence ability, any creature that fails a Wisdom saving throw while starting their turn in the DBS's aura is either Charmed or Frightened. There is no saving throw after the initial saving throw and therefore, the 1 minute of being Charmed or Frightened is mandatory (I'm also presuming that this aura lasts for a turn, and isn't active for the rest of the session).

While in the case of a creature being Frightened, there is a chance of breaking from the aura by attacking the DBS and breaking concentration, Charmed has the following effect:

> A charmed creature can’t Attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful Abilities or magical Effects.

As the Charmed creature cannot attack the DBS, would it be a theoretically viable strategy for the DBS to use Draconic Presence to Charm a single opponent and then keep making attacks and spells until the 1 minute ends, fully knowing that the Charmed creature will never be able to attack the DBS?

Comment: Ive removed the bonus question, as it is a totally separate question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can I ask, why did you conclude "that this aura lasts for a turn, and isn't active for the rest of the session." I agree that the aura doesn't seem to last for the rest of the session, but since the description says "For 1 minute ... each Hostile creature that starts its turn in this aura...[can become] Charmed... until the aura ends," I concluded that the aura lasts for a minute.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme I assumed that the "For one minute..." was in reference to how long the creature which is Charmed/Frightened is affected as opposed to how long the Aura lasts. It's specified at the end that the affect lasts until the aura ends so it's a little confusing to me as to how much that "For one minute..." is referring to the duration of the Aura rather than the duration of the Conditions effect.

Comment: Interesting. But if the "for one minute" refers to how long the creatures is Charmed or Frightened, and the creature is said to be Charmed or Frightened "until the aura ends," then doesn't that mean the aura lasts "for one minute"?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with:

> I'm also presuming that this aura lasts for a turn, and isn't active for the rest of the session

The aura will be active as long as the sorcerer concentration remains up.  So a newly-arrived creature that starts its turn in the aura will be affected also.  Auras travel with a character and affect creatures within its area of effect.

As to your question:

> would it be a theoretically viable strategy for the DBS to use Draconic Presence to Charm a single opponent and then keep making attacks and spells until the 1 minute ends, fully knowing that the Charmed creature will never be able to attack the DBS?

Of course.  As to whether or not that's a good strategy would depend on what that enemy is doing to other PC's.  The sorcerer is protected regardless, but other party members can still be attacked by the charmed creature.

Comment: Thanks! In regards to how long the aura lasts, does that mean that it stays up in perpetuity unless the Sorcerer loses their Concentration?

Comment: @gan, yes, for 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

Unless the sorcerer is in a solo adventure (or in a 1v1 arena combat), the counter to this ability is simply to attack someone else. The sorcerer is presumably traveling with other people, so attack them instead of the sorcerer.

The Charmed condition is remarkably weak when there are other targets; Frightened is far better at battlefield control.